# Firefox WebExtension: Input type="color" closes extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon

I developed a small extension where different words on the page are highlighted in different color. The user can pick a color for a specific word using `<input type="color` />.
This extension was made using chrome, with no issues at all regarding the color picker.
In firefox, however, a new window opens with a color picker.

**The main issue is that firefox closes the popup's extension when the color picker is opened. The change event on the color picker is ignored, because it is stored in the popup.js file.**

I already saw a question about this issue on stack overflow with no answers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a custom js colorpicker library.

Comment: You may think to convert the extension popuo to a window popup.  Yoy may also consider the firefox "sidebar" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Sidebars).   Both roads are to be tested